# Iterate over OBJECTS that has nearly the same name

Tags: python

I am creating this topic because I would like to iterate over Objects that have nearly the same name without having to copy/paste the code a lot of times.

For instance let's say we have a "class Car " and we have :
100 instances of Car like that :

```
Car_1 = Car()
Car_2 = Car()
...
Car_100 = Car()
```

How can we iterate over these objects ?
PS : In case eval() is a solution, I don't want to use that since string processing takes a long time

Comment: What makes you think that "string processing takes a long time"?

Answer (score 0):

When you want a lot of `Car()`s, you put them in a list. Then it is easy to iterate over them:

```py
cars = [Car() for _ in range(100)]
for car in cars:
    car.honk()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @quamrana, but for some reason I don't have them as a list because they come from another environment, I mean I just have access to each one. In other words, I'm not the one creating them, they're already created and accessible

Comment: That makes no sense. You had better get them in a list as soon as possible. The answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables) should help you.